# React hooks, component is reading old data from Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

My component is set to display a list of books, as card thumbnails. Each item from the list of books is generated by this component.
Each Card has a favorites icon, when clicking it adds the book to `favoriteTitles` array. By pressing again on the favorites icon it removes it from the list.

```
const Card = ({ title, history }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { favoriteTitles } = useSelector(({ titles }) => titles);
  const { id, name, thumbnail } = title;
  const [favorite, setFavorite] = useState(favoriteTitles?.some(item => item.titleId === title.id));

  const handleFavoriteClick = () => {
      const isFavorite = favoriteTitles?.some(item => item.titleId === title.id);
      if (isFavorite) {
      dispatch(removeFavoriteTitle(title));
      setFavorite(false);
    } else {
      dispatch(addFavoriteTitle(title));
      setFavorite(true);
    }
  };

  return (
  <CardContainer>
    <Thumbnail thumbnail={thumbnail} />
    {name}
    <FavesIcon isActive={favorite} onClick={handleFavoriteClick} />
  </CardContainer>
  );
};
```

The issue with this component is when you press once on `FavesIcon` to add, and if you changed your mind and want to remove it and press right away again, the `favoritesTitles` array still has the old value.

Let's suppose our current favorites list looks like this:

```
const favoritesTitles = [{titleId: 'book-1'}];
```

After pressing on favorites icon, the list in Redux gets updated:

```
const favoritesTitles = [{titleId: 'book-1'}, {titleId: 'book-2'}];
```

And if I press again to remove it, the `favoritesTitles` array inside the component is still the old array with 1 item in it. But if I look in Redux the list updated and correct.

How component should get the updated Redux value?

#### Update

I have specific endpoints for each action, where I add or remove from favorites:

`GET: /users/{userId}/favorites` - response list eg `[{titleId: 'book-1'}, {titleId: 'book-2'}]`

`POST: /users/me/favorites/{titleId}` - empty response

`DELETE: /users/me/favorites/{titleId}` - empty response

For each action when I add or remove items, on success request I dispatch the `GET` action. Bellow are my actions:

```
export const getFavoriteTitles = userId =>
  apiDefaultAction({
    url: GET_FAVORITE_TITLES_URL(userId),
    onSuccess: data => {
      return {
        type: 'GET_FAVORITE_TITLES_SUCCESS',
        payload: data,
      };
    },
  });

export const addFavoriteTitle = (userId, id) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  return dispatch(
    apiDefaultAction({
      method: 'POST',
      url: SET_FAVORITE_TITLES_URL,
      data: {
        titleId: id,
      },
      onSuccess: () => {
        dispatch(getFavoriteTitles(userId));
        return { type: 'SET_FAVORITE_TITLE_SUCCESS' };
      },
    })
  );
};
```

My reducers are pretty straight forward, I'm not mutating any arrays. Since only `GET` request is returning the list of array, I don't do any mutating in my reducers:

```
case 'GET_FAVORITE_TITLES_SUCCESS':
  return {
    ...state,
    favoriteTitles: action.payload,
  };
case 'SET_FAVORITE_TITLE_SUCCESS':
  return state;
case 'DELETE_FAVORITE_TITLE_SUCCESS':
  return state;
```

Comment: create a sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/)

Comment: Can you show, how you handle removeFavoriteTitle action in reducer ? it seems like you are mutating array instead of returning a new one. Also useState is completely unnecessary here - you can have just `const favorite = favoriteTitles?.some(item => item.titleId === title.id);` then you do not need setFavorite at all

Comment: `it removes it from the list.` What list, I don't see any code generating a list. Are add/removeFavoriteTitle thunk actions? Since favorites is in redux state you may want to get isFavorite from a selector using reselect.

Comment: Thank you guys, for your comments, I have updated my question with the actions and reducers, also to give you a better context I have added the endpoints and some additional info, that might be useful for you. Check the Update section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that by the time you click `FavesIcon` second time after adding to favourites, `GET: /users/{userId}/favorites` request is still pending and `favoriteTitles` list is not updated yet. That's why the component still contains an old value.

You need to update `favoriteTitles` list right away after triggering `addFavoriteTitle` or `removeFavoriteTitle` actions, without waiting `GET_FAVORITE_TITLES_SUCCESS` action to be dispatched. This pattern is called 'Optimistic UI':

```
export const toggleFavorite = itemId => {
  return {
    type: 'TOGGLE_FAVORITE',
    payload: { itemId },
  };
}

export const addFavoriteTitle = (userId, id) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch(toggleFavorite(id));
  return dispatch(
    ...
  );
};

export const removeFavoriteTitle = (userId, id) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch(toggleFavorite(id));
  return dispatch(
    ...
  );
};
```

And your reducer can look something like this:

```
case 'TOGGLE_FAVORITE':
  return {
    ...state,
    favoriteTitles: state.favoriteTitles.map(item => item.titleId).includes(action.payload.itemId)
      ? state.favoriteTitles.filter(item => item.titleId !== action.payload.itemId)
      : [...state.favoriteTitles, { titleId: action.payload.itemId }],

  };
```

**UPD.** Please, check out a minimal working [sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-redux-expample-08dce?file=/src/components/Card/Card.js)

Comment: Thanks for your response @oozywaters. Your logic makes sense, but when I tried it, it's the same issue I described in the very beginning. The `Card` component has the same old values. For example, having 1 book to favorites, I click on. book-2 to add and the Redux gets updated `[{titleId: 'book-1'}, {titleId: 'book-2'}]`, When I click again, to remove book 2, `addFavoriteTitle` action gets triggered again. because the component `favoriteTitles` still has 1 item in the array. So I'm back to square one, don't know what to do

Comment: It's really difficult to say what's wrong without seeing your code. I created a minimal example of adding/removing cards from favourites that you can check out in my updated post. Hope this will help to fix your app.

Comment: Your solution worked in the end, had to compare my code and the sandbox example and found the error. Thanks so much for your effort.